# COBOL - bonus report

Tags: count, character, cobol

Need your help with my COBOL assignment.

data division file section details are below.  My question is I do not know how to count the number if characters  - RECORD CONTAINS *_* CHARACTERS. Could you check and tell me if my count is right. If not what is the correct number and how did u arrive at it.

```
      FD  BONUS-REPORT

     RECORD CONTAINS 222 CHARACTERS.
     01  BONUS-REPORT-RECORD          PIC X(222).

    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01  LINE-CT                      PIC 99   VALUE 0.
    01  WS-CONSTANTS. 
        05 TOTAL-LINES               PIC 99   VALUE 10.
    01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS       PIC X(3) VALUE 'YES'.
        88 MORE-RECORDS              VALUE 'YES'.
        88 NO-MORE-RECORDS           VALUE 'NO'. 
    01  WS-DATE.
       05 WS-YEAR                   PIC 9(4).
       05 WS-MONTH                  PIC 99.
       05 WS-DAY                    PIC 99.
    01  HDR-1.
       05                           PIC X(40).
       05                           PIC X(12)
                              VALUE 'BONUS REPORT'.
       05                           PIC X(8).
       05                           PIC X(5) VALUE 'PAGE'.
       05 PAGE-NO                   PIC 99   VALUE 0.
       05                           PIC X(4).
       05 DATE-OUT.
          10 MONTH-OUT              PIC 99.
          10                        PIC X    VALUE '/'.   
          10 DAY-OUT                PIC 99.
          10                        PIC X    VALUE '/'.   
          10 YEAR-OUT               PIC 9(4). 
   01  HDR-2.
       05                           PIC X(10).
       05                           PIC X(13)
                                  VALUE 'TERRITORY --'.
       05 TERRITORY-NO-OUT          PIC X(2).
   01  HDR-5.
       05                           PIC X(20).
        05                           PIC X(10)
                              VALUE 'OFFICE -- '.
       05 OFFICE-NO-OUT             PIC X(2).             
  01  HDR-7.
      05                           PIC X(10).
      05                           PIC X(14)
                              VALUE 'EMPLOYEE NAME'.
      05                           PIC X(8).
      05                           PIC X(5)
                              VALUE 'BONUS'.                         
 01 DETAIL-LINE.
       05                           PIC X(7).
       05 EMPLOYEE-NAME-OUT         PIC X(24).
       05 BONUS-OUT                 PIC $BZ,ZZZ.99 BLANK WHEN ZERO.
```

Comment: TBH, I didn't know anyone got COBOL assignments any more.  Is it some sort of punishment?

Comment: Lots of COBOL still out there, someone has to take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to count them all and add them up, but it seems like you might be long.

It's not explicitly stated here, but it looks like your record in your `BONUS-REPORT` is probably a `REDEFINES` of the `HDR-n` and `DETAIL-LINE`, so the count of the longest of these is the record size (assuming fixed length records).

Count `BONUS-OUT` as 10. There should not be alignment because everything is `USAGE IS DISPLAY` by default. The `VALUE` clauses make no difference in the count.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking bonus record is 222 bytes because that what you say it is:--

```
  01  BONUS-REPORT-RECORD          PIC X(222).
```

What you probably are asking is what is the length of the various header and detail entries.

Normally these would all be written as *separate* records -- so the longest record would be HDR-1 at 81 bytes. All the others are shorter.

Comment: I count HDR-1 out as 81 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to ask the compiler for the answer.

That is, compile the program as-is and check the compiler listing and it should tell you how long each field and record is. Then you can go back into the source code and update as needed.

Depending on which enviroment you are using (mainframe, unix, windows, etc.) there might be certain compiler options that need to be set to tell the compiler create that kind of compiler listing.  For me using z/OS on the mainframe with the 4.2 release of the compiler, the options are all documented in the Enterprise COBOL for z/OS Programming Guide at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pdthelp/v1r1/topic/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rpcos390.htm.